# CMUSphinx live speech recognition too slow?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

CMU Sphinix is toooo Slow for recognizing live speech.I don't know if you have any idea for boost it?

This is my configuration:

```
configuration.setAcousticModelPath("WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz");
configuration.setDictionaryPath("cmudict.0.6d");
configuration.setLanguageModelPath("en-us.lm.dmp");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are currently working on speedup, but for now sphinx4 is not realtime for large vocabulary. It's actually not a trivial task.

If you want a fast and not very accurate transcription you can edit default.config.xml in sphinx4 sources and recompile:

```
  <property name="absoluteBeamWidth"  value="10000"/>
  <property name="relativeBeamWidth"  value="1e-60"/>
  <property name="absoluteWordBeamWidth"  value="50"/>
  <property name="relativeWordBeamWidth"  value="1e-40"/>
```

Then it will work realtime.